# classifying a column based on other column and append to new column

Tags: python, pandas, binning

This is the dataset I have, intuitively, Firm represents the unique firm identifier. y1, y2, y3 represents the number of employees they have. prob_y1, prob_y2, prob_y3 are the probabilities of number of employees. I need to classify prob_y1, prob_y2 and prob_y3 based on the values of y1, y2 and y3. I have attached function to classify those.

```
   Firm  y1    y2    y3   prob_y1   prob_y2   prob_y3
0     A   1     2     7  0.006897  0.000421  0.002729
1     B   2     3    45  0.013793  0.000632  0.017544
2     C   3     4    40  0.020690  0.000842  0.015595
3     D   4     7     3  0.027586  0.001474  0.001170
4     E   5     9     4  0.034483  0.001895  0.001559
5     F   6   400    12  0.041379  0.084211  0.004678
6     G   7    50    32  0.048276  0.010526  0.012476
7     H   8    70     0  0.055172  0.014737  0.000000
8     I   9    95    76  0.062069  0.020000  0.029630
9     J  10    98     1  0.068966  0.020632  0.000390
10    K  20     2    45  0.137931  0.000421  0.017544
11    L  30    10  2000  0.206897  0.002105  0.779727
12    M  40  4000   300  0.275862  0.842105  0.116959


def func(x):
    """this function is used to compute the bin"""
    if x < 5:
        return "binA"
    elif x >= 5 and x<10:
        return "binB"
    elif x >=10 and x<20:
        return "binC"
    elif x>=20 and x<30:
        return "binD"
    elif x>=30 and x<50:
        return "binE"
    elif x >=50 and x<100:

        return "binF"
    elif x>= 100 and x<200:
        return "binG"

    elif x>=200:
        return "binH"
    else:
        return 'binUnc'
```

when I run the following code, I get a result set what I am looking forward to.

```
for i in df:
    if i !='Firm':

        df[i] = df[i].apply(func)

    print(df)

   Firm    y1    y2    y3 prob_y1 prob_y2 prob_y3
0     A  binA  binA  binB    binA    binA    binA
1     B  binA  binA  binE    binA    binA    binA
2     C  binA  binA  binE    binA    binA    binA
3     D  binA  binB  binA    binA    binA    binA
4     E  binB  binB  binA    binA    binA    binA
5     F  binB  binH  binC    binA    binA    binA
6     G  binB  binF  binE    binA    binA    binA
7     H  binB  binF  binA    binA    binA    binA
8     I  binB  binF  binF    binA    binA    binA
9     J  binC  binF  binA    binA    binA    binA
10    K  binD  binA  binE    binA    binA    binA
11    L  binE  binC  binH    binA    binA    binA
12    M  binE  binH  binH    binA    binA    binA
```

My desired results is as follows:

```
Firm y1 biny1   y2  binY2   y3  biny3   prob_y1 biny1   prob_y2 biny2   prob_y3 biny3
A   1   binA    2   binA    7   binB    0.0069  binA    0.0004  binA    0.0027  binB
B   2   binA    3   binA    45  binE    0.0138  binA    0.0006  binA    0.0175  binE
C   3   binA    4   binA    40  binE    0.0207  binA    0.0008  binA    0.0156  binE
D   4   …   7   ….  3   binA    0.0276  …   0.0015  …   0.0012  binA
E   5   ….  9   ….  4   ….  0.0345  …   0.0019  ..  0.0016  …
```

In crux, what I am doing is classifying those probabilities values (prob_y1, prob_y2 and prob_y3) based on values of y1, y2 and y3. the new columns could be appended at the end, I added for demonstrative purpose only.

**Solution provided by user3483203 worked for me.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) here.

***Setup***

```
b = np.array([5, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100, 200, np.inf])
l = np.array([f'bin{i}' for i in 'ABCDEFGH'])
# l = np.array(['bin{}'.format(i) for i in 'ABCDEFGH'])
cols = ('y1', 'y2', 'y3')
```

---

Create a helper function using `digitize`:

```
def foo(cols, bins, labels):
    for col in cols:
        yield (f'{col}_bin', labels[np.digitize(df[col], bins)])
        # yield ('{}_bin'.format(col), labels[np.digitize(df[col], bins)])
```

Use `assign` to append to the DataFrame:

```
df.assign(**dict(foo(cols, b, l)))
```

```
   Firm  y1    y2    y3   prob_y1   prob_y2   prob_y3 y1_bin y2_bin y3_bin
0     A   1     2     7  0.006897  0.000421  0.002729   binA   binA   binB
1     B   2     3    45  0.013793  0.000632  0.017544   binA   binA   binE
2     C   3     4    40  0.020690  0.000842  0.015595   binA   binA   binE
3     D   4     7     3  0.027586  0.001474  0.001170   binA   binB   binA
4     E   5     9     4  0.034483  0.001895  0.001559   binB   binB   binA
5     F   6   400    12  0.041379  0.084211  0.004678   binB   binH   binC
6     G   7    50    32  0.048276  0.010526  0.012476   binB   binF   binE
7     H   8    70     0  0.055172  0.014737  0.000000   binB   binF   binA
8     I   9    95    76  0.062069  0.020000  0.029630   binB   binF   binF
9     J  10    98     1  0.068966  0.020632  0.000390   binC   binF   binA
10    K  20     2    45  0.137931  0.000421  0.017544   binD   binA   binE
11    L  30    10  2000  0.206897  0.002105  0.779727   binE   binC   binH
12    M  40  4000   300  0.275862  0.842105  0.116959   binE   binH   binH
```

Comment: yeah, thanks user3483203, the f-strings interpolation does not work for my python version. is that backward compatible? but I can use 'bin{%i}'%i

Comment: @lpt I have added the equivalent lines using `str.format`

Comment: we did at the same time. But thank you. this is much better. if you'd comment saying that f-string wont work for v <3.6.2 that would be great for other users if they come across this.

Answer (score 1):

You can using `pd.cut` to replace your function

```
bins=df[['y1','y2','y3']].apply(lambda x : pd.cut(x,[-np.inf,5,10,20,30,50,100,200,np.inf],labels=['binA','binB','binC','binD','binE','binF','binG','binH']))
```

Then we using `reindex` to append the new dataframe bins back to original df

```
newdf=pd.concat([df,bins.reindex(columns=df.columns[1:].str.split('_').str[-1])],axis=1)
```